# Unable to use docker inside a circleci job

Tags: docker, circleci

This is my circleci configuration file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build: 
    docker:
      - image: 12345678.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/circleci/build:20180319
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install docker
          command: |
            apt-get update --fix-missing
            apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
            curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
            apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
            add-apt-repository \
              "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
              $(lsb_release -cs) \
              stable"
            apt-get update
            apt-get install -y docker-ce
            docker --version
      - run:
          name: Build and deploy docker images
          command: |
            docker build -t myapp .
```

The 'Install Docker' is basically modeled after the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/.

When the job executes to the line `docker build` I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

So I tried to `service start docker` before the build task. But now I get this error:

```
 /etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
```

It is due to a restriction of docker. It does not allow `ulimit -u <a large number>`

How can I get around this restriction and start the docker daemon?

Answer (score 2):

Add a step `setup_remote_docker` before the use of docker. i.e.

```
  - setup_remote_docker
  - run:
      name: Build and deploy docker images
      command: |
        docker build -t myapp .
```